# Uploaded verified local fXL epubs don't open in Google play books

Tags: epub, google-play-books

My fixed layout epub is verified with epubcheck-4.0.1: no errors, no warnings. On ibooks and Readium: no problems at all.

I upload the file to my google play books library on Chrome, Firefox, safari. The epub doesn't open and gets stuck with "Processing..."  keeping displayed.

Now, I 'buy" a free fixed epub from the google play books store. The epub opens. I downloaded the epub. Upload it again. Now it doesn't open any more. Message: "This book cannot be opened
This book contains content that is not yet supported in your browser."

I try the same procedure on an Android device. Same behavior.

I am stuck and would be grateful to have a few hints to move from this gridlock.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to read a local epub on the playbook reader within a browser. The native play books reader must be installed instead.